# SASS Font Import nesting issue

Tags: reactjs, sass

Within my react app I have a folder structure like so:

```
src
 -assets
   -fonts
 -components
   -NormalComponents
   -ContentCards
     -CardType1
     -CardType2
 -containers
 -styles
 etc
```

I'm importing a mixin.scss file which is located within the `styles` folder. This contains a mixin function to import fonts from the following path: `src/assets/fonts/myfonthere.ttf`

Here is my function:

```
@mixin font-face($font-family, $file-path) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: $font-family;
        src: url('#{$file-path}.eot');
        src: url('#{$file-path}.woff');
        src: url('#{$file-path}.ttf');
    }
}

@include font-face(MyFont-Bold, '../assets/fonts/MyFont-Bold');
```

I can import this mixin with no errors at the `src/components/NormalComponents` level however, when I to import at `src/components/ContentCards/CardType1` errors are thrown.

**Error**: `Module not found: Can't resolve '../../assets/fonts/MyFont-Bold.eot'`

Is this due to the nested folder structure for the Content Cards component? Is there any way around this so I can import the mixin at any level and not have this issue?

Comment: Use the path relative to your CSS file, not your Sass files.

Comment: If I do that, how can I import the mixin then use it within my file?

Comment: I mean for urls, not imports. Since your Sass files are compiled into a single CSS file, you need to use your CSS file as relative path for your fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a problem about nested folder structure.Is it possible that you import mixin file from styles directory, after add a more doctor ,your {file-path} has something wrong?

Comment: Potentially, after further debugging I think the issue lies where I'm trying to import a file that's located three folders deep, where the path to the font only goes as high as two - hence why it works at normal component level. I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: Why not only define font-family in mixin,and import it in your js files.

Comment: Import within my js files? I didn't know that was possible.